# Check if album art exists?

Tags: android, android-glide, mediastore, android-music-player, albumart

I'm building a music player app. I'm trying to populate a `recyclerView` with album arts of songs. I successfully did that with the code that is given below. But some of the songs do not have embedded album art not any album art in the folder. So, I'm trying to check if the album art is null or not before adding it to the `recyclerView`. If the album art is null, the app will automatically fetch it from the internet. I tried checking if the album art is null or not, but everytime it gives me a `uri` whether the album art is available or not.

Code for fetching album art from mediastore:

```
 String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, whereVal, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                Long duration = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                Long albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                String albumArtUri = String.valueOf(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),albumId));


 SongInfoModel s = new SongInfoModel(id, name, artist, null, album, null, duration, data, albumId,albumArtUri);
                SongList.add(s);



            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

The value for albumArtUri is never null.

It always gives the following uri(s):

```
content://media/external/audio/albumart/12
content://media/external/audio/albumart/5
content://media/external/audio/albumart/6
content://media/external/audio/albumart/3
content://media/external/audio/albumart/8
content://media/external/audio/albumart/9
```

But among these uri(s), `content://media/external/audio/albumart/9` has no album art. It always displays the placeholder I said using `Glide`

So my question, how to check if album art is available(as embedded art or in song folder) before populating the `recyclerView`? I know I can use `Glide` placeholder and I'm using it. But I also want to fetch album art from the internet if album art is not available offline, that is why I need to check, so that I can add the internet links into the arraylist. Hope you guys get what I'm trying to say.

Thank you!

**EDIT**:

I found that the below given code snippet returns if album art exists or not but it consumes a lot of time.

```
  public String fetchAlbumArt(long albumID){

    String art;
    Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]
            {MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART}, MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(albumID)}, null);

    cur.moveToFirst();
    art = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));

    cur.close();

    return art;
}
```

Comment: You want to read the actual file and check. Have you looked at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever. Otherwise use a third party library such as audiotagger or jid3 to read mp3 tags

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```
                //  loading album cover using Glide library
            String stralbumId = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

            Uri ImageUrl = getAlbumUri(mContext, stralbumId);
            if (ImageUrl != null) {
                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(ImageUrl)
                        .into(image);
            }
```

and

```
  public Uri getAlbumUri(Context mContext,String album_id){
if(mContext!=null) {
    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(sArtworkUri, String.valueOf(album_id));
    return imageUri;
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: @Rektirino would be nice if you acknowledged if this has been helpful/useful

Comment: This just returns null if your context was null. Whether the album art exists doesn't influence this at all.

Answer (score 2):

you can check for album cover by using the `MediaMetadataRetriever`
try the code below and also read the `MediaMetadataRetriever` [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#summary)

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriver.setDataSource(musicFile.getAbsolutePath());
byte[] cover = retriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
if(cover == null){
  // get cover from the internet 
}else{
  // use glide to load the album art
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below

```
var albumArtExists = true
try {
     val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, albumId)
     context.contentResolver.loadThumbnail(contentUri, Size(64, 64), null)
} catch(e: FileNotFoundException) {
     albumArtExists = false
}
```

This works for sdk 29 and higher